# How to SRC files from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

This code works perfectly on my local machine but I would like to move it to AWS Lambda

I have already uploaded ffmpeg as a binary dependency to the function layer

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.call(
    'ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i "./ep1.png" -i "./ep1.mp3" -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=1280:720 ep1.flv', shell=True)
```

Question is How do I replace

```
"./ep1.png"
```

and

```
"./ep1.mp3"
```

as an understandable path for the ffmpeg command

This is documentation I found from boto3 but I'm not sure how to implement it

```
 s3 = boto3.client('s3')
 s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')
```

Let me know if I'm heading in the right direction, after this step I would use boto3 to upload ep1.flv to an output S3 bucket

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda functions can store data in the `/tmp/` directory.

So, you could use:

```
 s3.download_file('my-bucket', 'ep1.mp3', '/tmp/ep1.mp3')
 s3.download_file('my-bucket', 'ep1.png', '/tmp/ep1.png')

p = subprocess.call(
    'ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i "/tmp/ep1.png" -i "/tmp/ep1.mp3" -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=1280:720 /tmp/ep1.flv', shell=True)
```

Also, make sure you delete the files in `/tmp/` before your function exits because the container might be reused and there is only 500MB of storage provided.